# Infinite positive integer question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

> Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $m$ for which
> $$18^{m}+45^{m}+50^{m}+125^{m}$$
> is divisible by $2006$

I am not sure of an approach to these type of divisibility problems when coming across in a book of contest questions, like the powers of $m$. What is a way to solve it?

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1258019p6515634 for a proof, and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h81719p468320 for another that replaces the brute force step in the first thread with a quadratic residue argument.

Comment: Beware that both answers are incorrect - see the comments there.

Comment: Please have the courtesy to add some context or attempts to your question, else the question will likely be closed and deleted by some users, thus wasting the effort of all  the answerers.

Answer (score 4):

The [second thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h81719p468320) I linked did not show clearly how the quadratic residue applies to show that the exponent $29$ is not accidental. Here is an expansion of their idea:

We have $2006 = 2 \times 17 \times 59$ as the prime factorization.

For every $m$, $18^m + 45^m + 50^m + 125^m$ is even.

Taking mod $17$, the expression is equivalent to $1^m + (-6)^m + (-1)^m + 6^m$, which is zero for all odd $m$.

The hard part is taking mod $59$. It is equivalent to $$18^m + (-14)^m +(-9)^m + 7^m = (9^m + (-7)^m)(2^m+(-1)^m)$$

Hence we need to find odd $m$ such that $9^m \equiv 7^m \pmod {59}$.

We check that $7$ is a quadratic residue of $59$, either by quadratic reciprocity:

$$\left(\frac7{59}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{7-1}2\frac{59-1}2}\left(\frac{59}7\right)=-\left(\frac37\right)=1$$

since it is easy to check $3$ is not a quadratic residue mod $7$, or by observing

$$7 \equiv 59\times 6 + 7 = 361 = 19^2$$

Hence for some $a \in \mathbb Z$, we have $7^m \equiv a^{2m} \pmod {59}$.

By Fermat's Little Theorem, $a^{2m} \equiv 1 \pmod {59}$ when $m \equiv 29 \pmod {58}$.

Similarly, $9^m = 3^{2m} \equiv 1 \pmod {59}$ when $m \equiv 29 \pmod {58}$.

Hence $9^m \equiv 7^m \pmod {59}$ when $m \equiv 29 \pmod {58}$.

To conclude our findings, for every $m \equiv 29 \pmod {58}$, the expression is divisible by $2006$.

Comment: Incorrect because $\,125 \bmod 59 = 7,\,$ not $\,9.\ \ $

Comment: Fixed. $ {} {} $

Comment: I added an answer that eliminates the need to factor, and clarifies why it works.

Answer (score 1):

This Lemma solves the only nontrivial case: mod $\,p = 59\,$ (use reciprocity to check squareness).

**Lemma** $ $ Suppose $\,p=4j+3\,$ is prime and $\!\bmod p\!:\! \color{#0a0}{\,a,b\ \rm are\ nonsquares},\,$ $\color{#c00}{\,c,d\ \rm are\ squares}.\,$ Then there are infinitely many odd $\,m\in\Bbb N\,$ such that $\,p\mid a^m+b^m+c^m + d^m$.

**Proof** $\ $ Let $\, e = (p\!-\!1)/2 = 2j\!+\!1\,$ and let $\,k\in \Bbb N\,$ be odd, so $\,m := ek\,$ is odd.

Then by [Euler's Criterion:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) $\!\bmod p\!:\ \,\color{#0a0}{a^e,b^e\equiv -1},\ \color{#c00}{c^e,d^e\equiv 1},\,$ thus

$$\begin{align} 
&\ \ \ \ \,a^m\ \ +\ \ b^m\  +\, \ c^m\  +\ d^m\\[.2em]
= &\ \ \  (\color{#0a0}{a^e})^k  + (\color{#0a0}{b^e})^k\! +\! (\color{#c00}{c^e})^k\! +\! (\color{#c00}{d^e})^k\\[.2em]
\equiv &\ \ (\color{#0a0}{-1})^k\! +\! (\color{#0a0}{-1})^k + \color{#c00}1^k + \color{#c00}1^k\\[.2em]
\equiv &\   \ \ \,{-}1\ \, +\ \, {-}1\ \ +\  1\ +\ 1\\[.2em] 
\equiv &\ \ \ \ 0
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$